# How to return a character string to another function?

Tags: c

I am wrting a function which pads a few characters on either right or left depending on the user's choice. I used strcat function to concat the characters to the string and it worked fine in case of right padding, but while left padding I got junk characters so I wrote my own concat function. Still the same result please see the code below.

```
char *concat(char a[], char b[])
{
    int len1=0, len2=0, i, j;
    char tmp[100], *tmp2;
    trace("concat(): Begin");
    len1 = strlen(a);
    len2 = strlen(b);
    for(i=0, j=0; i<(len1+len2); i++)
    {
        if(i<len1)
            tmp[i]=a[i];
        else
            tmp[i]=b[j++];
    }
    tmp[i]='\0';
    tmp2 = tmp;
    sprintf(str, "Concatenated String: %s", tmp2);
    trace(str);
    trace("concat(): End");
    return tmp2;
}

char *pad(char *field_name, char *field_val)
{
    char *temp_var=field_val, *temp_var2;
    int i=0;
    char pad_var[100];

    trace("pad(): Begin");
    sprintf(str, "field name to search for: %s and field value to be formatted: %s", field_name, field_val);
    trace(str);
    get_format_vars(field_name);
    sprintf(str, "strlen(field_val) = %d and len = %d", strlen(field_val), len);
    trace(str);
    if(strlen(field_val)<len)
    {   
        trace("Data should be Padded"); 
        trace(field_val);
        for(i=0; i<len-strlen(field_val); i++)
        {   
            pad_var[i] = pc;
        }
        pad_var[i]='\0';
        sprintf(str, "pad_var = %s", pad_var);
        trace(str);

        switch(pd)
        {
            case 'l':
            case 'L':
            sprintf(str, "length of field: ", strlen(field_val));
            temp_var = concat(pad_var, field_val);
            sprintf(str, "Value after left padding: (%.*s)", len, temp_var);
            trace(str);
            break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            strcat(field_val, pad_var);
            temp_var = field_val;
            sprintf(str, "Value after right padding: (%s)", temp_var);
            trace(str);
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
        trace("No formatting to be done for this field");
        break;
        default:
            trace("Wrong value for padding type.");
    }
    trace("Data Padded");

}
else
{   
    trace("Field length already equal to format length");
}
temp_var2 = temp_var;
sprintf(str, "Data after/without formatting: (%s)", temp_var2);
trace(str);
trace("pad(): End");
return temp_var;
}
```

Please note, the above program works completely fine in case of right padding.

Please let me know what is it that I am doing wrong due to which when I do left padding, it displays junk characters at the end.

**Note: The functions and variable whose reference is not there in the program are declared globally in my program like the function "trace" and the variable "pd".**
trace() function takes a string parameter and writes that string to a file.

Comment: Have you followed/watched it in a debugger to see what/when/where the problem starts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: Returning string from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733308/c-returning-string-from-function)

Comment: Fix the indention, this is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not write your own version of strcat.
2. You should not return an automatic (local) array - it's out of scope after the function returns, using it invokes undefined behavior.

Either `malloc()`ate some memory and return that dynamically allocated chunk or memory, or call the functions with an input/output argument, which is an array declared in the **caller** (as opposed to the callee).

Comment: Stack contents are not normally modified by returning from the function. The value is only lost when the stack is used again to make the second call.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas Don't speculate. UB is UB.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a pointer to a temporary stack variable that goes out of scope when the function exits.  Its memory may (will) then be reused by other function calls.  The easiest fix would be to allocate memory dynamically in `concat` then `free` it in the caller.

```
char* tmp = malloc(len1+len2+1);
```

You could also simplify your `concat` function to

```
char* tmp = malloc(len1+len2+1);
strcpy(tmp, a);
strcat(tmp, b);
return tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but what I don't understand is that why does strcat not work when I am using it for left padding while it works in right padding.

Comment: Glad you've got this working.  I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question.  `strcat` looks for the null-terminator in a dest string and appends a src string at this point.  If you had a sufficiently large dest string which started with your 'padding' bytes, you could use `strcat(dest, src)`

Answer (score 1):

You allocate result you return on the stack inside the returning function:

```
char tmp[100]
```

This may even actually *work* (contents of the usual, "classic" stack are not broken by return), but only as long as you use or copy the returned string immediately somewhere else without making another call. As soon as you make the second call (system call including), stack is reused and you get garbage.

Assigning the reference to another variable before return has no effect.

Use one of the [strdup](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strdup.3.html) family functions to return a cloned copy (do not forget to free when no longer needed).